# Best portable DB engine that supports Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net

I need to know what is the best portable db, for this situation

I've an application base on sql server db, we use both LINQ TO SQL, and ADO.NET, in this application.

Now we need to make a portable version of it, but the fact we are using Linq To Sql, preventing us from using MS Access, as there is not out of the box solution for that (other than some 3rd parties, and we don't want to use them).

So I need to a db engine that is:

- Portable
- Have Linq support.

if it is not completely portable, is there is a one that can be easily attached & deattached, from client PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code project article: [LinqToSQL: Comprehensive Support for SQLite, Microsoft Access, SQServer2000/2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linqToSql_7.aspx)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, I'm searching right now about SQLite, it seems it will be good.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check out SQL Compact Edition?

[Downloadable for free](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876) and a [list of reasons why to use it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx)

It seems the latest and greatest version (4) does not support LINQ-to-SQL, but the [previous version (3.5) does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546181.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I guess it will be the SQLite the winner here :)